# How to disable a monitor gnome/linux

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display

Since gnome uses wayland for login,
(I know i can disable it in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and then use `xrandr` or `xorg.conf`, but that's not the way i want)
Is there a way to disable, enable a monitor?
This would be nice to have, once gnome fuly switches to wayland.
I got this far:

- The kernel already supports the things that xorg warps, thats why the wayland protocol was created
- Mutter is the window manager of gnome, but the command-line tool has nothing useful to offer.
- I can disable the monitor via the grub kernel parameters, but i don't know how to enable it back once ubuntu is booted (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=VGA-1:d"`).

I need this because i have an older laptop(hp elitebook 2570p), and it can only output to two monitors at the same time. So if i have 3 monitors connected to the laptop(LVDS, VGA, DP).
The video isn't outputted right, kb doesn't work, etc. Basically i can't login and have to poweroff the laptop, unplug one monitor and power the laptop back on.